# Android APV pdf reader crashes upon opening PDF

Tags: android, pdf

I followed the instructions on the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/Building) for apv-0.3.3: chose pro version with python command, then used the current building method by running scripts/build_native.sh. No problems or errors yet.
Then I imported the project into eclipse from the folder pdfview. I had an error saying "The return type is incompatible with View.getRotation()", so I commented the getRotation() function in PagesView.java out. When I ran the project on the emulator, every time I opened a PDF I got the following error in LogCat:

```
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at cx.hell.android.pdfviewpro.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:541)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at cx.hell.android.pdfviewpro.OpenFileActivity.startPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:502)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at cx.hell.android.pdfviewpro.OpenFileActivity.onCreate(OpenFileActivity.java:219)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pdfview2: findLibrary returned null
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     at cx.hell.android.lib.pdf.PDF.<clinit>(PDF.java:25)
09-05 18:46:33.008: E/AndroidRuntime(1652):     ... 17 more
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be it is little bit late

try with moving your `PDF.Java` in package `cx.hell.android.lib.pdf`